# How to bind a IEnumerable with ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, model-binding

I have an IEnumerable which isgetting values from JSON in pagebehind:

```
   IEnumerable jsonData = default(IEnumerable);
   jsonData = GetJsonValues(URL);
```

Now I have a collection which contains :

> Title = "Some Title" and
>   Thumbnail = "URI as String"

Now I have my XAML Containing ListBox:

```
 <ListBox Width="480" Height="280" x:Name="listBoxJsonData" />
```

How do I bind jsonData with  listBoxJsonData.

I dont want to use  `listBoxJsonData.ItemsSource = jsonData;`

Comment: *I dont want to use listBoxJsonData.ItemsSource = jsonData;*: why ?

Comment: Want to do that using Binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a property of it and use MVVM pattern to bind using DataContext.

This way (Not tested) inside a new class say `ViewModel.cs`

```
private IEnumerable jsonData;

public IEnumerable GetJSonData
{
    get
    {
        if (jsonData == null)
        {
            jsonData = GetJsonValues("http://www.viki.com/api/v2/channels.json");
        }
        return jsonData;
    }
}
```

and in XAML

```
<ListBox Width="480" Height="280" x:Name="listBoxJsonData" 
         ItemSource="{Binding 
                      ElementName=Name_of_Window_where_this_listbox_is, 
                      Path=GetJSonData}" />
```

and in window constructor

```
this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

Comment: Tried with  <ListBox Width="480" Height="280" x:Name="listBoxJsonData"  ItemsSource="{Binding  ElementName=CurrentWindowName, Path=GetJSonData}"> but saying there are no propertey with name GetJson , set the DataContext too